# How do I remove trailing digits fitting a pattern from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-2.0

I have the following string: `0000015700`

I need an algorithm that does the following:

- goes to the first digit other than `0` from right to left (`7`, in this case)
- extracts 6 digits starting from `7` going right to left (output would be `000157`

It cannot be implemented using LINQ, since the project is running on the .NET 2.0 framework.

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: sorry for that but I have none to achieve this.

Comment: It's not complex at all. You have my answer down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should trim end of string, and then get a required substring:

```
var tmp = str.TrimEnd('0');
var result = tmp.Substring(Math.Max(0,tmp.Length - 6));
```

Comment: As well as the possibility of failure if there are fewer than 7 non-zero digits, shouldn't this be `tmp.Length - 6` rather than `tmp.Length - 7`? We only want to take 6 digits, not 7.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri And obviously you meant TrimEnd('0') not TrimeEnd('0'); Note the typo :)

Comment: @John Gathogo Yes both typo and bad english :) fixed

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care about performance too much and you've got LINQ, you could do:

```
var result = new string(text.Reverse()
                            .SkipWhile(c => c == '0')
                            .Take(6)
                            .Reverse()
                            .ToArray());
```

Hopefully that should be pretty self-explanatory :)

Comment: Hm I've just posted the same ... :))

Comment: I don't think linq is good here, when we can use native string functions, and they should be faster and easier to use.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I don't know - personally I find my version easier to understand here. In particular, I think your code might actually have a bug at the moment...

Comment: Thnx for the solution but I have to do it without LINQ.

Comment: @Piyush: Any reason you didn't mention this before? In that case, Saeed's approach is probably best. In future, please include requirements in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that Jon, I really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 3):

So as I understand you want the 6 digits starting from anything other than 0 from the right. Use regular expressions.

```
^.*([0-9]{5}[1-9])0*$
```

I have no experience in C#, but it looks like this should work:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

[...]

Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^.*([0-9]{5}[1-9])0*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

With this the string doesn't even need to have trailing zeroes (will work with trailing zeroes as well with no trailing zeroes).

Comment: In .NET Regex, Groups[0] returns the complete match, so this wouldn't work -- it would return the whole input string as long as it matches. To get the captured section in parens, however, you just need to change that to `Groups[1]`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, my C# skills are unexistant. Answer edited.

Comment: there is `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` options perhaps you would be able to leverage it somehow

Comment: It's quite a simple regex, no need to simplify anything IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

…   

var source = "0000015700";
var pattern = @"\d{5}[1-9](?=0*$)";
var result = Regex.Match(source, pattern);
if(result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[0]);
}
```

If you aren't familiar with regular expressions, it is a language for string pattern matching that is embedded in just about every general purpose programming language. The pattern above will match your input string if:

`\d{5}` : you have 5 consecutive digits
`[1-9]` : followed by any digit between 1 and 9 (not zero)
`(?=0*$)` : followed by zero or more `0`s and `$` denotes the end of the string

Because I put that last bit in `(?= )`, the engine knows that that stuff must be there, but should not be part of the match; this is called "positive lookahead"

Comment: So complicated? Wouldn't my answer's regex work in that case?

Comment: This will capture *only* the desired 7 characters. Your regex result will have 2 groups, the first of which will contain all characters before and all zeros after the desired 7.

Comment: Jay as I know you in previous challenges, you are regular expression master, but really in this simple case is it required to use regular expression?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri It is never required to use regular expressions, but it is a logical fit for most pattern-matching scenarios. One advantage is that there is no hard-coded algorithm, only the pattern. The pattern can be read-in from configuration at runtime, for example, so there is greater flexibility for things to evolve without having to rework existing code.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "0000015700";
string result = new string(
    input.Reverse()
            .SkipWhile(ch => ch == '0')
            .Take(6)
            .Reverse()
            .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string.LastIndexOf to find the first non-zero digit from right to left, see example below:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224422.aspx

Then do a string.substring of the index returned by string.LastIndexOf

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:
in a for loop, find the last index of the zero character. If it's the same as the last index of the array, remove it.

Comment: Too slow, too long and too ugly. Can be done shorter, cleaner and faster.

Comment: Also this does not resolve the question since he stated that he needs 6 characters and not the whole string without the trailing zeroes.